# Border image in ionic 3 is not working? How can use it in ionic 3

Tags: ionic3

**I Need border like shown in picture**
[Click here to see the image border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOQfJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you were following ionic css guidelines,
you will get to know about it more here **[Link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/css-variables)**

**CSS some how look like this**

--background-image: url(../images/jonty-rhodes.png);

--background-position: bottom;

--background-repeat: no-repeat;

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I tried your solution but in android its working perfectly, but in ios along with bottom little more everywher around its showing the border

Comment: And yes I am following the guidelines

Comment: Where you are checking that it wont work in ios. In Xcode, In mobile ?